# Wifi signal boost through walls

Tags: wireless-networking, signal-strength

I need to set up a private wireless network to stream video, between 2 buildings that are 300 meters apart. The problem is that there is not a LOS (line of sight). I thought of using multiple hotspot/routers/acces points.

What would you recommend?

---

This should be accomplished without any tower-like antenna, i can deploy within a room with a window.

Comment: Silly question perhaps but can you or do you already have ethernet laid (or coas or phone wire or... taught strings)?

Comment: Do you own/have access to the intervening buildings?

Comment: I just have access to one apartment in each building, but these should deploy without "installing" anything on the building itself

Answer (score 2):

I would use a directional antenna to accomplish your objective. Point this at the other building, but like the description of the item, it is directional. You need to be precise when you point it. You can get really powerful antennas that would be overkill for what you need.

Comment: Check updated Q, So if i use a directional antenna will it go through an entire building?

Comment: Depends on the type of building. That's why most details won't tell you exactly on product pages. I don't know what else you expect to do it with. For wireless transmissions, the only way you can improve distance is with antennas. Another option could be network extenders, but that may take a lot of them to do something like that, maybe 5-10 wireless extenders... And those are still antennas, but you are just using a lot of them for something that you could probably do with just one bigger one. Let me know if you have any other questions!

Comment: Also, when I say directional, I do not mean omnidirectional. Usually, omnidirectional will not have the distance you want. If you have just a directional antenna, it will go only in one direction, but it will be much stronger and go further in that one direction.

Answer (score 0):

If no line of sight, it is much more complex than an antenna.  You will need something to get teh signal to teh other end by adding another device (perhaps more) to get the sight line. 802.11 signals are 2.4GHz and they attenuate badly on things like concrete, wood and even a very leafy tree.

It may be possible to bounce a signal off a reflective surface but that is tricky as controling bounce direction can be a challenge.

Can you add more info on the exact layout of the two buildings?

Comment: I dont have the layout yet, will wimax 802.16 work?