# NanoStation M2 wifi through walls

Tags: wireless-networking, wireless-router, wireless-access-point, hotspot

My question is similar to this one [Wifi signal boost through walls](https://superuser.com/questions/350023/wifi-range-singal-boost-through-walls)

I will like to know if a wifi signal from a NanoStation M2 can pass through walls?

I am  a newbie, and the reason I chose NanoStn M2 over M5 is that I often read that 2.4 GHz can pass through walls and trees but with 5 GHz it may be difficult. (Maybe I got it wrong)

I have a a CPE from my ISP that has in-built wifi-router, I can access (use) this though 4 walls (signal is weak though). My E2500 (dd-wrt) also give similar performance. My task now is to boost the signal so that its stronger even in other buildings around (< 250m radius). Limitation here is the power source - only reliable power exists at the server location.

I installed NanoStn M2 outside the server building, I can't get the signal even in the room where my CPE gets to. I even increased Distance to 12Km - no way. I think something is wrong some where.

Answer (score 0):

Nanostation M2 or even the Loco M2's dont do well with walls especially solid like concrete, steel or brick. I've done a few installations with them and the signal usually drops about 50 to 70% with a solid wall, Also I wouldn't consider them omni direction as the signal behind it is alot weaker than in front, ALOT!!.